# ASP.NET TreeView checkboxes behave as Radio Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, treeview, postback

I'm using a TreeView Control on ASP.NET with C#, and needs to make all the nodes (Roots and Leafs) with checkboxes. Then, I need these checkboxes to work as Radio Buttons so when clicking on one checkbox, the previously checked checkbox is now unchecked and the new one is becoming checked.

My work on this problem was first to add *showCheckBoxes="All"* attribute to the asp:TreeView then to use the TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged event. However, this event is not triggered automatically and needs a **postback** for the page to fire up!
So I used a **javascript** function to make it fire up as recommended on similar posts in stackoverflow.com but for different problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postBackByObject() {
        var o = window.event.srcElement;
        if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
            __doPostBack("", "");
        }
    }
</script>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          TreeView1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "postBackByObject()");    
        }
```

However, still I couldn't figure out how to write the **TreeNodeCheckChanged** function to make the previously checked checkbox unchecked , and make the new one checked! As the post back action is making a confusion for me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, you could do this 100% client side.

We would on page load:

Select the treeview.

Then select any check boxes showing and add a click event.

And in that click event?

get the check box we cliked on - save setting.

Uncheck all check boxes.

Check/uncheck the one we clicked on back to its state.

This seems to work:

```
    <script>
        // select all check boxes - add event to that check box
        // on page load

        $(window).on('load', function () {
            tv = $('#TreeView1')
            nodes = tv.find('input[type=checkbox]')
            nodes.each(function () {
                $(this).change(function () { mycheck(this) } )
            })
        })

        function mycheck(e) {
            mychecked = e.checked    // save current check box
            myParent = $(e).closest('[id$=Nodes]')     // get current node
            clist = myParent.find('input[type=checkbox]')  // get all checkc box in node
            clist.each(function () {
                this.checked = false     // uncheck them all
            })
            e.checked = mychecked        // set state of the box we checked or un-checked.
        }
    </script>
```

So, I get/see this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to put your code inside the HTML Page of my asp.net project but it didn't work for me for some reason. I put the script as it is inside the <head> tag of the WebForm1.aspx page. Am I missing something to be added in the cs file for example?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that you used jQuery which I don't use in my code, so it worked fine after I added the CDN link to my scripts. Could you please adjust the code without jQuery and make the action work for all checkboxes not just the Leaf ones. I mean when you press on a checkbox all other checkboxes become unchecked even in other Roots. Thanks

Comment: The video shows two different leaf's, and I am able to check and un-check boxes as per the video shows me checking and un-checking boxes in 2 different leafs. Using jQuery, and no, I don't have a non jQuery solution anymore then I am willing to go to your house, and clean your clothing, take out your garbage and then clean your room. jQuery selectors are beyond helpful in this solution. Get a working jQuery solution, then start a new question asking for help to convert to non jquery. Without more information, we are shooting in the dark as to what extra checkbox's you are referring to.

Comment: Possible that your root leaf's have a check box, but I thought the question was to only being able to select one item inside a leaf/node. If  root check box is allowed, then you are suggesting that one root as opposed to items inside of a leaf being selected. As such, much a different question then what I understood. You seem to be suggesting that root leaf's also have a check box, but that suggests in most cases that all child items are being selected then??? So, are you suggesting that roots have a check box then? A screen cap and layout of your tree would help a lot here

Comment: Sorry if there is any ambiguity in my question, I was indicating to uncheck other Leaves in other Roots. Anyway, I think what you have provided is enough to be considered as a solution to my question suppose I take an extra step to figure out a vanilla JS code from your code. Thanks man.

Comment: Break that jQuery issue down to another question (by default, quite sure any standard asp.net site or template includes jQuery.. We can only bite one part of an elephant at a time. It not a big deal that some details were left out - I can only answer on the given details (and I well happy to admit it could be my miss-reading or lack of providing a solution. No real worries. I could test/try adding check boxes to the roots and see what occurs. if I have time later today, I try with check boxes on roots. Most cases check of a root means to check/select all child's for most UI setups.

Comment: Never Mind my friend, **really appreciate your efforts**. I studied your code and found a similar way using vanilla JS as follows 

`<script type="text/javascript">
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
    const cbName = e.target.id;
    for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].id != cbName)
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
    }
});
</script>`

Comment: All good then. Perhaps I become a bit too lazy in regards to using jQuery as a crutch, but no worries.